# BadImageFormatException is thrown after a few days

Tags: c#, .net

I've gone through several posts about `BadImageFormatException` but I couldn't find answer to my situation.

I've a C# project that uses few 3rd party DLLs. The project's runtime is `.NET Framework 4.8`. I build the project using "Any CPU" configuration in VS 2022. An installer is built and the software is distributed through the installer.

On the end user's `Windows 10 x64` machine, the software runs fine for a few days. After that suddenly the software stops launching. When tried to launch, Windows generates the following event logs:

```
Application: <application name>.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
```

and

```
Faulting application name: <application name>.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x6215bc3a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.535, time stamp: 0x5bd9df62
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x001135d2
Faulting process id: 0x610
Faulting application start time: 0x01d82c9bac0533c9
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\<application path>
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 0c7bbce1-7a2b-47f5-a95a-083860aad054
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Surprisingly, replacing the .exe file with the original .exe file solves the problem and makes the software starts again.

What could be the possible reason for this? How to fix it?

I've checked all of the 3rd party DLLs with file command that all of them are built as 32 bit DLL.

Comment: They might be infected with a virus? Maybe some ransomware? Or an overly aggressive anti-virus?

Comment: Or a dying spinny hard drive.